# Magento 2.4 How to get category of current product from within ViewModel without using objectManager?

Tags: magento2, category, phtml, viewmodel

**This works but uses objectManager**

```
namespace Myvendor\Myprogram\ViewModel;

class CatLogic extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements     \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
public $variable;
public function __construct() {
    $this->variable = "works";
}

public function getProductCatagory()
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
    $arr =[];
    foreach($categories as $category){
        $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);
        $arr[] = $cat->getName();
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

}

**phtml file**

```
$viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');
$categories = $viewModel->getProductCatagory();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get rid of the object manager you need to move all classes that are needed to the construct method using dependency injection.

Please have a look and try this modified code

```
<?php

namespace Myvendor\Myprogram\ViewModel;

class CatLogic extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{
    public $variable;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModel
    ) {
        $this->variable = "works";
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->categoryModel = $categoryModel;
    }

    public function getProductCatagory()
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
        $arr =[];
        foreach($categories as $category){
            $cat = $this->categoryModel->load($category);
            $arr[] = $cat->getName();
        }
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

You will need to run bin/magento setup:di:compile command to get this viewmodel working with the new injected classes

Comment: I appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: can you please upvote and accept the answer if it's working?